# Use Cursor in SQL store procedure to call another store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

the below procedure should fetch all the procedures stored in the the VisitorFunctions  table. Currently it just fetches and executes for the last entry in the table.

I have used cursor as an option but that does not seems to work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Visit]
    @visitPoint nvarchar(100),
    @recordType nvarchar(100),
    @id int,
    @username nvarchar(56)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- TODO: Do we need to support multiple visitors (e.g. School and Asset?)
    declare @typeSpName nvarchar(100)
    declare @spName nvarchar(100)
    select @spName = v.StoredProcedure from VisitorFunctions v join VisitPoints vp on vp.Id = v.VisitPointId where vp.Name = @visitPoint and v.RecordType = @recordType

    -- if SemanticWeb then get the node type
    if @spName is not null and @recordType = 'SemanticWeb'
    begin
        ;with recurSet(parentId)
        as
        (
            select templateId
            from sw.CoreData
            where ID = @id

            union all

            select p.parentId
            from sw.Template p
            join recurSet rs on rs.parentId = p.ID
            where p.ParentID is not null
        )

        select @typeSpName = v.StoredProcedure 
        from recurSet rs
        join VisitorFunctions v on v.SemanticWebNodeTemplateId = rs.parentId and v.RecordType = @recordType
        join VisitPoints vp on vp.Id = v.VisitPointId and vp.Name = @visitPoint

        if @typeSpName is not null
        begin
            set @spName = @typeSpName
        end
        else
        begin
            set @spName = null
        end
    end

    -- call it
    if @spName is not null
    begin
        declare @sql nvarchar(max) = @spName + ' ''' + @recordType + ''', ' + cast(@id as nvarchar) + ', ''' + @username + ''''
        exec sp_executesql @sql
    end
END
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?.

Comment: Did not see your cursor